# Wordpress the_title filter is duplicating title

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running this code:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'ekins_titlefilter', 1, 2);
function ekins_titlefilter( $content, $id = null) {
    if(($id !== null) && ($content !== null)) {
        if(is_single($id) && in_the_loop()) {
        if ( null !== the_field('subscriber_title', $id)) {
            return the_field('subscriber_title', $id);  
        }
        }
    } 
        return $content;  
}
```

Which currently should show the "subscriber_title" custom field instead of the regular title (This will eventually only show to logged in subscribed users, but trying to get this basic functionality working first). However its replacing the title correctly, but the subscriber title is also being shown at some random places on the page such as above the header, and on the blog post list its showing the replacement title AND the original title (For example "New TitleOld Title") is there any other checks i can code in that will make it only replace it in two cases, titles on the page itself, and titles on links to go to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem `return the_field('subscriber_title', $id);`.

`the_field` function outputs (echo) the value, you need to change it to `get_field`

Comment: Wow. Such a simple solution! Thank you, thats now working perfectly. I have spent literally a hour reading through the wordpress documentation to work out what the problem was.

Comment: For future reference, `the_field` and `get_field` are ACF functions, not wordpress functions. Im guessing thats why you could not find anything about them when looking in wordpress docs